# ecryptfs: auto-umount does not work

Tags: unmounting, ecryptfs

I've set up an encrypted home directory for user piranha3:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ecryptfs-verify -u piranha3 -h
INFO: [/home/piranha3/.ecryptfs] exists
INFO: [/home/piranha3/.ecryptfs/Private.sig] exists
INFO: [/home/piranha3/.ecryptfs/Private.sig] contains [2] signatures
INFO: [/home/piranha3/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt] exists
INFO: [/home/piranha3] is a directory
INFO: [/home/piranha3/.ecryptfs/auto-mount] Automount is set
INFO: Mount point [/home/piranha3] is the user's home
INFO: Ownership [piranha3] of mount point [/home/piranha3] is correct
INFO: Configuration valid
```

But after piranha3 logouts directory is not unmounted:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# mount | grep ecryptfs
/home/.ecryptfs/piranha3/.Private on /home/piranha3 type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=729061d7fa17b3a4,ecryptfs_sig=eb5ec4d9c13e2d74,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

lsof output:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() cifs file system /media/cifs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

System Information:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# dpkg -l ecryptfs-utils
Deseado=desconocido(U)/Instalar/eliminaR/Purgar/retener(H)
| Estado=No/Inst/ficheros-Conf/desempaqUetado/medio-conF/medio-inst(H)/espera-disparo(W)/pendienTe-disparo
|/ Err?=(ninguno)/requiere-Reinst (Estado,Err: mayúsc.=malo)
||/ Nombre                   Versión           Arquitectura      Descripción
+++-========================-=================-=================-======================================================
ii  ecryptfs-utils           103-5             armhf             ecryptfs cryptographic filesystem (utilities)
root@raspberrypi:~# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

And finally about PAM:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# grep -r ecryptfs /etc/pam.d
/etc/pam.d/common-session:session       optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/common-password:password     optional        pam_ecryptfs.so 
/etc/pam.d/common-auth:auth     optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive:session        optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```

Why is not /home/directory unmounted?

Comment: The `ecryptfs-verify` option `-p` is for a private non-HOME directory, try the `-h, --home` option instead. And do any encrypted homes for any other users work correctly, mount on login & umount on logout, etc? Created with `adduser --encrypt-home` or with `ecryptfs-migrate-home` ?

Comment: I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @sebelk I'm facing the very same issue with my home folder created with `ecryptfs-migrate-home` in archlinux. I followed the [wiki instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs) for auto-mounting. It is mentioned there that there is a bug with `systemd`, a bug report is filed and [a workaround is provided](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-systemd-maintainers/2014-October/004088.html) but I am far from a systemd specialist.

Comment: I believe I found a way that is working for me on Ubuntu 17.04 - Information below.in Answer section.

Comment: I posted answer in another thread. I found a solution to this issue on 16.04 and 18.04. [link to other post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910484/encrypted-home-folder-still-accessible-after-logout/1052885#answer-1052885 "link to other post")

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and follow these instructions.

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
sudo nano ecryptfs-umount-private.service
```

Enter the content below into the file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Umount Private directory
Before=systemd-exit.service
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=shutdown.target
After=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ecryptfs-umount-private

[Install]
WantedBy=exit.target
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then press `y` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to save the file.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ecryptfs-umount-private.service
```

I have tested this and it is working for me.

One other thing that I did that may or may not help was to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change the line `#KillUserProcesses=no` to `KillUserProcesses=yes`.

P.S. I tested this by switching users, logging out, logging back into primary account and then testing with root with `ls /home/folder name`.  I noticed a small delay, however this worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

According to an user at askubuntu it's a known bug: https://askubuntu.com/a/932650. Don't know if it's true or not, but I found a workaround.

I added at the end of my .bash_logout (e.g. vim ~/.bash_logout) following line:

```
(sleep 10; ecryptfs-umount-private) &
```

When I logout (ssh connection), I see the message "Sessions still open, not unmounting", but my home-dir gets unmounted/encrypted anyways.